# convert Queryset to array

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe, django-queryset

Have been trying to work on this for some sometime maybe my mind is rusty so i am seeking another mind for help.

Below is a queryset coming from the database:

```
0    01
1    ()
Name: 0, dtype: object
0    02
1    ()
Name: 1, dtype: object
0    03
1    ()
Name: 2, dtype: object
0    04
1    ()
Name: 3, dtype: object
0    05
1    ({'id': 1, 'qty': 1}, {'id': 2, 'qty': 2})
Name: 4, dtype: object
0    06
1    ()
Name: 5, dtype: object
0    07
1    ()
Name: 6, dtype: object
0    08
1    ()
Name: 7, dtype: object
0    09
1    ({'id': 2, 'qty': 1})
Name: 8, dtype: object
0    10
1    ()
Name: 9, dtype: object
0    11
1    ({'id': 1, 'qty': 1})
Name: 10, dtype: object
0    12
1    ()
Name: 11, dtype: object
```

if there is no consumption for equipment in this particular month the the query will return an empty tuple as in the below example for the first 4 month :

```
0    01
1    ()
Name: 0, dtype: object
0    02
1    ()
Name: 1, dtype: object
0    03
1    ()
Name: 2, dtype: object
0    04
1    ()
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

if there is consumption for equipment in this particular month, the query would return the id of the equipment and the qty used.like month '05':

```
0    05
1    ({'id': 1, 'qty': 1}, {'id': 2, 'qty': 2})
Name: 4, dtype: object
```

I want to map this query set to a Pandas Dataframe that would have the months as columns that contains the 'qty' and the rows would the equipment id, below picture to illustrate more the requirement how i want the template table output to look like.

[Dataframe required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyNXr.jpg)

would appreciate your input!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: edited with more details